# QGIS problem with PostgreSQL/PostGIS column permissions

Tags: qgis, postgis

If a create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE streetmap.ways (
    pk bigserial not null,
    name character varying(150),
    geom geometry(LineString,32628),
    rowdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    username character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "current_user"(),
    CONSTRAINT ways_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pk)) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE ) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

And assign all permissions (`GRANT ALL ON TABLE streetmap.ways TO qgis_editor`) to qgis_editor user, everything works fine with QGIS 3.

But if instead I set:

```
GRANT SELECT(pk, rowdate, username) ON streetmap.ways TO qgis_editor;
GRANT ALL(name, geom) ON streetmap.ways TO qgis_editor;
```

Or:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE streetmap.ways TO qgis_editor;
GRANT ALL(name, geom) ON streetmap.ways TO qgis_editor;
```

QGIS 3 can´t edit the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you're asking why, if you fail to grant write access to a table, a user can't write to it? Isn't that self-evident?

Comment: + GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO user;

Comment: OP wants to give write permissions just for two attributes of the table. Uncommon use case, not surprised that it is not supported by QGIS.

Comment: Hi @Vince if you set columns permissions as I did, you can execute "insert into streetmap.ways(name, geom) values ('Main St', wkt_geom)". You can try it using pgAdmin. So I didn´t fail granting permissions. It seems that QGIS use only table permissions.

Comment: It seems that it doesn´t solve the problem @Mapperz .With first option (grant all columns only), QGIS doen´t show the table in Navigator panel connection but you can see it contents in "db manager". With second option (grant table and a subset of columns) QGIS show the table in Navigator panel and "db manager" but it treats this table as read-only.

Comment: Maybe @user30184 but I think that supporting this uncommon use case avoid unwanted changes in a better way than marking controls as "non-editable".

Comment: You've failed to grant access to the thing for which QGIS (or any other product, for that matter) is likely to ask -- After "List the tables to which I have SELECT access" comes, "Do I have INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE access on this table?" And the (correct) answer is "No". You'd need to make significant changes to the edit model to capture *some* columns being more editable than others (and implement that for half a dozen databases)

Comment: @Vince I think the short and easy answer is QGIS doesn´t support PostgreSQL column permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When QGIS issues a query, you'd have to know what it's sending. **Consider enabling verbose logging on the server so you can see it.**

My guess is that QGIS tries to update every column in the table. For instance,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( id int, a int, b int );
```

Then an update to `a` where `id=1` would be like this,

```
UPDATE foo SET a=?, b=? WHERE id = 1;
```

Even if you don't have `b=` in the update query, QGIS, and most applications will set it to whatever they think it is, **like it's previous value**. This is normally a good thing, as any update to an MVCC database requires rewriting the entire row.

In your case, it's not a good thing.

**That's going to be a huge problem.**

I doubt QGIS cares to implement column-level permissions.

Comment: I doubt it too.